# Previewing all uploaded photos, not just one

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to preview a user's selected photos tp upload before they are actually uploaded. So far, I have one photo being previewed, how do I allow all to be previewed

I have the input field here, with the multiple keyword to allow multiple files be chosen. Next I have a preview pane for the photos followed by a jQuery script which renders a preview when a file is selected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style>
  img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <input id="myFile" type="file" multiple><br>
  <img class="preview"><br>
  <button>Upload</button>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script>
    $("#myFile").change(function(event) {
      var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        $(".preview").prop("src", this.result);
      };
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
      var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0],
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        fd = new FormData();

      xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
      fd.append("fileToUpload", file);
      xhr.open("POST", "upload.php"); //this is the file accepting the upload
      xhr.send(fd);
    });

    function uploadComplete() {
      //do something when finished uploading
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you'll need to loop over the `files` collection of the file input, then create a new reader for each image before appending a new `img` element for each selected file. Something like this:

```js
$("#myFile").change(function(event) {
  var $previews = $(".previews").empty();
  [].forEach.call(this.files, function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      $previews.append(`<img src="${this.result}" />`);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="myFile" type="file" multiple><br />
<div class="previews"></div><br />
<button>Upload</button>
```

Also note that your `<style>` element is outside of the HTML structure. It should be placed inside the `<head>`. Or better still, use an external stylesheet and reference it with a `<link>` element

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a million.